# Call to a member function update() on null LARAVEL

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I tried to update specific item but it was error 'Call to a member function update() on null'.
I tried to change ->update($data) with ->insert($data) before and it works.

Controller:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $this -> validate($request, array(
            'gamename' => 'required|min:3',
            'price' => 'required|int|min:1',
            'genre' => 'required',
            'releaseddate' => 'required|date',
            'picture' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif'
        ));


        $gamename = $request->input('gamename');
        $genre = $request->input('genre');
        $price = $request->input('price');
        $releaseddate = Carbon::parse($request->input('releaseddate'));
        $picture = $request->file('picture')->getClientOriginalName();

        $data=array('gamename' => $gamename, 'genre'=>$genre, 'price'=>$price,'releaseddate'=>$releaseddate,'picture'=>$picture );

        DB::table('games')->join('genres', 'games.genreid', '=', 'genres.genreid')->find($id)->update($data);

        return redirect('managegame');
    }
```

View:

```
<form action="/update/{id}" method="post" id="registerform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="errorpop{{ $errors->has('genre') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
            <label for="genre" class="">Genre</label>

            <div class="">
                @foreach($genres as $genre)
                    <option value="{{ $genre->genreid }}">{{ $genre->genre }}</option>
                @endforeach
                @if ($errors->has('genre'))
                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('genre') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                @endif
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: it gets the game's id which i clicked to edit || i got the same result as i use  {{ $id = $_SESSION['id'] }} @AlexeyMezenin

Comment: So, this gives you an object then `dd(DB::table('games')->find($id))`? and not `null`? If it does, do this `DB::table('games')->where('id', $id)->update($data)`;

Comment: yes it's not `null`, i've tried your answer. it doesn't show any error but it's only refresh the _edit page_ (it should be redirect:view) without updating the data

Comment: Sounds like validation redirects back, try to remove validation. Will the game be updated?

Comment: DB::table('games')->where('id',$id)->update($data); should work, working fine on my end, just tested

Comment: sorry i've edited the HTML the name genre with genreid. it's not error now, and the page is redirected now, but the data is not *updated* :(

Answer (score 2):

`{id}` not a value. You must have value for `{id}` . 
Example: `action="/update/1"`

```
<form action="/update/1" method="post" id="registerform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="errorpop{{ $errors->has('genre') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
            <label for="genre" class="">Genre</label>

            <div class="">
                @foreach($genres as $genre)
                    <option value="{{ $genre->genreid }}">{{ $genre->genre }}</option>
                @endforeach
                @if ($errors->has('genre'))
                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('genre') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                @endif
            </div>
        </div>
```

Then to update you use method `where('id', $id)` replace `find($id)`

```
DB::table('games')->join('genres', 'games.genreid', '=', 'genres.genreid')->where('id', $id)->update($data);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#updates

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you got the object

```
$game = DB::table('games')->
join('genres', 'games.genreid', '=', 'genres.genreid')->where('id',$id)->get();
```

//make sure you have the desired object.then

```
  $game->update($data);
```

Comment: i've tried your answer. it doesn't show any error but it's only refresh the edit page (it should be redirect:view) without updating the data

Answer (score 0):

I'm nor sure this line works as you expect

`DB::table('games')->join('genres', 'games.genreid', '=', 'genres.genreid')->find($id)->update($data);`

What are you trying to update? `games` or `genres` ?  You can't update 2 tables at once like that.  You'd need to find the `games` row to update, update that that, and the joined table row, and update that, cannot do it all at once.

But the fact that you're trying to update 2 tables from one simple form, in the same method suggests that your tables is not properly laid out?

Answer (score -2):

id)->update($data);

```
    return redirect('managegame');
}
```

View:

has('genre') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
            Genre

```
        <div class="">
            @foreach($genres as $genre)
                <option value="{{ $genre->genreid }}">{{ $genre->genre }}</option>
            @endforeach
            @if ($errors->has('genre'))
                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('genre') }}</strong>
                                </span>
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>
```